# Change JSON Object format function

Tags: javascript, json

I need to develop a Javascript function that can convert JSON format as the following. I am not sure if there is already a javascript function for this purpose or should i develop a new one on my own

Input: (example)

```
  {
            "event[id]": "1476258193",
            "event[creator]": "aziz",
            "event[title]": "event[title]",
            "event[review][thankyou]": "event[review][thankyou]",
            "event[review][teaser]": "event[review][teaser]"
    }
```

The Output should be something like that:

```
{
  Events: {
            Id: “1476258193”,
            Creator: “aziz”
            …..
            Review: {
                      Thankyou: “”,
                      Teaser: “”
}
}
}
```

EDIT (SOLUTION) : After some work and help from other users especially "anied" i did the function myself, if some one is interested here is a plunker with the answer, the function is not 100% optimal but it does what should do
https://plnkr.co/edit/4d6cDzHXpN3RAOAJD2F0?p=preview

```
    convert = function() {
  var obj = {
    "event[id]": "1476258193",
    "event[creator]": "smista",
    "event[title]": "event[title]",
    "event[crmid]": "event[crmid]",
    "event[responsible]": "event[responsible]",
    "event[location]": "event[location]",
    "event[ktr]": "event[ktr]",
    "event[description]": "event[description]",
    "event[targetgroup]": "event[targetgroup]",
    "event[learninggoals]": "event[learninggoals]",
    "event[status]": "offline",
    "event[issuu][html]": "event[issuu][html]",
    "event[group_by_threads]": "1",
    "event[timeblocks][0][lectures][0][persons][0]": "2",
    "event[timeblocks][0][lectures][0][persons][1]": "333333",
    "event[timeblocks][0][lectures][0][persons][2]": "3",
    "event[timeblocks][0][lectures][1][persons][0]": "44",
    "event[timeblocks][0][lectures][1][persons][1]": "444",
    "event[timeblocks][0][lectures][1][persons][2]": "4444",
    "event[participants]": "event[participants]",
    "event[review][thankyou]": "event[review][thankyou]",
    "event[review][teaser]": "event[review][teaser]"
  }

  var result = "Events : {";
  var mainKeyString = "" ;
  var mainKeys = [] ; 
  var keysCount = 0 ; 

  for (var k in obj) {
    if( obj.hasOwnProperty(k) ) {
      res = k.replace('event[', ''); 
      mainKeyString+= res ; 
    } 
  }
  mainKeyString = mainKeyString.replace(/\[/g,',');
  mainKeyString = mainKeyString.replace(/\]/g,',');
  mainKeyString = mainKeyString.replace(/,,/g,',');
  mainKeyString = mainKeyString.substring(0, mainKeyString.length-1);
  mainKeys = mainKeyString.split(',') ; 
    for (var i in obj) {
      if( obj.hasOwnProperty(i) ) {
        keysCount = (i.match(/\[/g) || []).length;
        var lastKey = keysCount -1 ; 
        for (j=0;j<keysCount;j++){
          if (keysCount >1 && j != lastKey){
            result += mainKeys[0] +": {"; 
          }
          else if (keysCount >1 && j == lastKey) {

              result += mainKeys[0] +":\""+obj[i] + "\"}";
          }
          else result += mainKeys[0] +":\""+obj[i] + "\",";
          mainKeys.shift() ; 
        }
      } 
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: You have to develop your own.

Comment: Can you give me any hints how to do that, that would be really appreciated thanks.

Comment: The use of `eval` is often frowned upon, but if you're just developing a script to convert that one JSON (only this time and not planning on keeping it running in some app or webpage or something) then I guess I'd consider it

Comment: Play with `Object.keys()` and `RegExp`

Comment: @Steeve Pitis Ok thanks ill check that out

Comment: @Martin Asquino can you please how can i use eval for this specific purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should develop something because I don't know that anything like that exists.  You will want to write a recursive method that iterates over the object keys and adds properties to a new source object.  However, one difficulty will be that you will also need to handle duplicates (of which I see a few).  If you can be confident of the format of the keys (that they only contain brackets to denote new properties), then you can write something that iterates over the keys in the object using a `for...in` loop (`for key in yourobject`) and looks for `substr(key.indexOf('['), key.indexOf(']')` to hunt down the logical delineations.  Good luck!

Comment: I have tried that but had some problems with the duplocates as you expected, but i'll work on that and let you know. Thanks anyway for the answer

Comment: No problem-- the problem is, the way that your original object was written, there _were_ duplicates-- if you don't want to overwrite the duplicates, you'll also need to handle them, which will mean the conversion isn't just a "converter", it's also a "validator/handler" which is going to be harder.  Good luck!

Comment: After some 4 hours of developing i have finally did it, i'll choose your answer as the best answer because you gave me the way thanks :).

Here's a plunker for the result it's not optimal yet but i'll get there: https://plnkr.co/edit/4d6cDzHXpN3RAOAJD2F0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the vote, and good on you for following-up with your solution-- that's all good StackOverflow etiquette.  As for handling the duplicates, yeah, it won't be super easy-- and it will be specific to your **requirements** of how duplicates must be handled.  I wish you luck!